# Integer Overflow in a problem while using cout statement although i am using mod

Tags: c++, printf, cout, integer-overflow, modulo

```
cout<<((n%mod*n%mod)%mod)
```

when the value of n is:

2248813659738258

my output is :

-840739582

However this problem is resolved when using 'printf' instead of `cout` the reason for this problem??.

Comment: There is no problem. Except `printf` being a C library function that's not type-safe, and shows the wrong results. It's the `printf` result that's incorrect.

Comment: Lot of things could be going wrong. Could we see a [mcve]?

Comment: What is the value of `mod`?  Your calculation of `n % mod * n` is probably overflowing.

Comment: I guess value of mod is 1000000009 right??

Comment: To prevent overflow, try: ((n%mod)*(n%mod)). Currently you effectively have ((((n%mod)*n)%mod)%mod) which is obviously not what you want, the second modulo is too late and the third modulo does nothing at all.

Comment: the value of 'mod' is 1000000007